# Error in Forming DOM element from XML parsed String

Tags: java, android, xml, dom

I am trying to get the `DOM` element from a `UTF-8` Encoded XML parsed file containing **arabic characters**. 
The below method take the parsed xml string and is supposed to return the Document.

**here is a link to the xml:**

`http://212.12.165.44:7201/UniNews121.xml`

```
public Document getDomElement(String xml){

    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        StringReader xmlstring=new StringReader(xml);
        is.setCharacterStream(xmlstring);
        is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
                    //APP CRASHES HERE
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    // return DOM
    return doc;
}
```

Error:

```
09-18 13:36:20.031: E/Error:(3846): Unexpected token (position:TEXT xml version="1.0...@2:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4144ac08)
```

**I would appreciate your help but please be specific in your answers**

Comment: please add the complete stackTrace (and a small xml that reproduces the problem)

Comment: kinddly check the update @njzk2

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: according to what i have seen, it is possible that the first <? is missing or not read from your xml string.

Comment: don't worry about it i handled this and its not the issue @njzk2

Comment: so whats the problem here @njzk2

Comment: i don't know, but could you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: I solved the problem, I changed StringReader to inputStream and it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

It happened a lot of times to me, you should double check the encoding of the file you are opening. I suggest you to test this with a local copy of the file where you set the encoding by hand.

Comment: even with other alphabets like the chinese one? could you perform a test?

Comment: btw i forgot to mention that I created the XML file so while saving i made sure to save in UTF-8 and the I posted it on the server so I dont think its a file issue

Comment: so what do you think the problem is @Gabber

Comment: Usually in my case is an encoding issue, but if you have encoded manually the file this is not the case. Did you try to repeat the test with a local file? or trying putting chinese characters in it

Comment: let me correct something I replaced the the arabic chars with english one and still it did not work ... so what do u think the problem is?